# If $A$ is positive semidefinite and $P$ is unitary, is $B = P^{-1}AP$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, unitary-matrices

I know that in general, positive semidefiniteness is not preserved by matrix similarity. But is it preserved when $B = P^{-1}AP$ and $P$ is unitary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, symmetry / Hermitianness of matrices is not preserved by a coordinate change. But diagonalizability and all eigenvalues being nonnegative reals (even the exact eigenvalues, including algebraic and geometric multiplicity) *is* preserved by general coordinate changes. That's because those are properties not of matrices, but of the underlying linear transformations, so coordinate changes do not matter.

A unitary change of coordinates *does* preserve symmetry / Hermitianness of matrices. So it will also preserve positive semi-definiteness.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: since $P^{-1}=P^*$,
$$
\langle x,P^{-1}APx\rangle=\langle Px,APx\rangle
$$

Comment: Should be $\left< x, P^{-1} A P x\right>$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes, thanks